# Repeatation of class while adding class in twig template

Tags: theming, 8

I want to add CSS class to `<li></li>` as shown in the following code. There are three `<li></li>` codes where I have added calss using `{{attributes.addClass('')}}`

***from book-navigation.html.twig***

```
{% if tree or has_links %}
  <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="book-label-{{ book_id }}">
    {{ tree }}
    {% if has_links %}
      <h2>{{ 'Book traversal links for'|t }} {{ book_title }}</h2>
      <ul>
      {% if prev_url %}
        <li{{attributes.addClass('page-previous')}}>
          <a href="{{ prev_url }}" rel="prev" title="{{ 'Go to previous page'|t }}"><b>{{ '‹'|t }}</b> {{ prev_title }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% if parent_url %}
        <li{{attributes.addClass('page-up')}}>
          <a href="{{ parent_url }}" title="{{ 'Go to parent page'|t }}">{{ 'Up'|t }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% if next_url %}
        <li{{attributes.addClass('page-next')}}>
          <a href="{{ next_url }}" rel="next" title="{{ 'Go to next page'|t }}">{{ next_title }} <b>{{ '›'|t }}</b></a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
  </nav>
{% endif %}
```

The output I am getting is with above code is,

> [image]

**But, I want as following,**

```
<ul>
  <li class="page-previuos"></li>
  <li class="page-up"></li>
  <li class="page-next"></li>
</ul>
```

Am I missing something, or there is other right-way to do that? Very Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add a class, but to replace the existing classes, you can use `setAttribute()`.

```
<li{{attributes.setattribute('class', 'page-previous')}}>
```

Comment: If there is not a way to add the single class per code of line, this method looks the easiest way for this solution!!!

Answer (score 1):

`.addClass()` will add the class to the previous class.

> The `.addClass()` function: A function returning one or more space-separated class names to be added to the existing class name(s).

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: What I want to do is, I just want to add separate class in each `<li></li>`, as shown in my last image. I think, there should be someway to do that. I can combine `.addClass()` and `.addRemove()` to  achieve that, but I think that could be the not right way.

Comment: One more thing to point out this is not related to jquery. I have reffered this [Using attributes in templates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates)

Answer (score 1):

We can use .removeClass() in the link classes to remove previous classes like this,

**Code** -

```
{% if tree or has_links %}
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="book-label-{{ book_id }}">
{{ tree }}
{% if has_links %}
  <h2>{{ 'Book traversal links for'|t }} {{ book_title }}</h2>
  <ul>
  {% if prev_url %}
    <li{{attributes.addClass('page-previous')}}>
      <a href="{{ prev_url }}" rel="prev" title="{{ 'Go to previous page'|t }}"><b>{{ '‹'|t }}</b> {{ prev_title }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
  {% if parent_url %}
    <li{{attributes.addClass('page-up').removeClass('page-previous') }}>
      <a href="{{ parent_url }}" title="{{ 'Go to parent page'|t }}">{{ 'Up'|t }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
  {% if next_url %}
    <li{{attributes.addClass('page-next').removeClass('page-up') }}>
      <a href="{{ next_url }}" rel="next" title="{{ 'Go to next page'|t }}">{{ next_title }} <b>{{ '›'|t }}</b></a>
    </li>
  {% endif %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
</nav>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Yes that is right, even I have achieved that by combining both methods, hence image-3 in posted in question came,  but I am looking for the method where we can simply add one class, if there is any.